# DataFlow Teradata Jdbc connection proporty string

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jdbc, dataflow, prefetch

I have nearly 3310000 millons data on teradata. When I want to transfer into the BigQuery via DataFloq, it takes nearly 20 minutes and that time is very high for the whole process.
To decrease the this process time , I have already tried to adjust **prefetch** and **fetchsize**, but  I got an error as Invalid connection parameter name. What can I do for this situation. Thanks in advance,
Best Regards

Comment: What is the exact error that you are receiving?

Comment: Error is "Invalid connection parameter name" ,  but today  I gave the experience=shuffle_mode_service options in additional experiment parts instead of setting up fetch_size. I need to decrease my reading operation while during a data flow execution. Do you have an idea/ suggestion about that problem.